# Injectivity condition of parametrised statistical manifold

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

I am currently learning information geometry by following this [note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.3369.pdf).  It starts by defining the set of probability distribution functions
$$
S=\{p_\xi=p(x,\xi)\mid \xi=(\xi_1,\ldots, \xi_n)\in O\subset \mathbb{R}^n\},
$$
where $p(x,\xi)$ is a probability distribution function  on space $\Omega$. It calls $O$ the parameter space, and requires $\xi\mapsto p_\xi$ to be injective, and $O$ is open.

However, I find the injectivity condition is very strong for many nonlinear models. For example, let us  consider  the  following softmax models:
$$
S=\left\{p_\xi(i)=\frac{e^{\xi_i}}{\sum^n_j e^{\xi_j}}, i=1,\ldots, n\mid \xi=(\xi_1,\ldots, \xi_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}.
$$
Even though $p_\xi(i)=\exp\left(\xi_i-\log(\sum^n_j e^{\xi_j})\right)$ is of the exponential form, the map $\xi\mapsto p_\xi$ is not injective. Indeed, $p_{\xi}=p_{\tilde{\xi}}$  if $\xi=\tilde{\xi}+C\boldsymbol{1}$ for any $C\in \mathbb{R}$, where $\boldsymbol{1}$ denotes the vector with all entries being $1$.  Similarly, for many neural networks, the parameterisation is noninjective. However the   optimisation problem    $\inf_{p\in S}J(p)$ can still be well-defined, in the sense that there exists a unique minimiser $p^\star\in S$ (associated with many parameterisations).

**Question**. May I know whether this injectivity condition is essential to apply the geometric techniques  to study the set $S$?
More precisely, can we still equip $S$ with   the well-known Fisher-information metric,
and make $S$ a Riemannian manifold?

If the injectivity is crucial, does it mean the information geometry is not suitable to study optimisation over softmax models, or more general neural network models? I am not sure whether there is a well-known technique to address this difficulty.

Comment: I says the parameter space is chosen so that the map is injective, that’s different from saying the map itself has to be injective. Right?

Comment: @FedePoncio For the softmax family, it is unclear to me what is a natural choice of open sets $\mathbb{O}$ such that the parameterization is injective, as $p_\xi$ is invariant for any constant shift of parameters. Do you suggest to introduce an equivalent class of parameters and works with the quotient space under the equivalence condition?

Comment: I would think that's the way to go, yeah. Mainly because what you need to do is map each distribution to its coordinate chart with $\phi (p_\xi) = \xi$, so without the injectivity condition I think that map wouldn't be well defined. I'm not an expert at all though.

Answer (score 1):

The injectivity condition may definitely be dropped in some cases. If the tangent map of $\xi\mapsto p_{\xi}$ is still injective at every point, then you'll be able to get a metric tensor which is non-degenerate even if your immersion map is not injective. If the tangent map of $\xi\mapsto p_{\xi}$  is not injective at some point, then you'll get a non-degenerate tensor at that point.

Regarding your specific example, the quotient procedure you and @FedePoncio mention in the comments is the way to go. In particular, since $\xi$ and $\tilde{\xi}+C\mathbf{1}$ gives the same probability vector, you may identify an equivalence class with a $\hat{\xi}$ such that the sum of its components is $0$.
Moreover, let me add that the parametrization you have in mind can be seen as the orbit through $\mathbf{1}$ of the action of $\mathbf{R}^{n}_{+}$ on the simplex given by
$$
\mathbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{1}\\\vdots \\ v_{n}\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \frac{1}{\sum_{k} \mathrm{e}^{\xi_{k}} v_{k}}\begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{\xi_{1}}v_{1} \\ \vdots \\ \mathrm{e}^{\xi_{n}}v_{n} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In this case, $\xi$ is an element of the Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$, and the lack of injectivity simply says that the action is not effective.